# CSS DIV width 100% goes over div

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV that has a width of 512px. Then inside that DIV is another DIV. I set the width of THAT DIV to 100%. However, it goes over which is not what I wanted.

I am trying to make it so it stays within the div. As in 5px padding on all sides.

http://jsfiddle.net/weka/USvTC/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem is happening because `padding` and `border` are not part of `width: 100%`.

Assuming you do want to absolutely position `#exp_wrap`, use this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/USvTC/1/

I removed `width: 100%` on `.bar_wrap`/`#exp_wrap`, and added `right:5px;` on `#exp_wrap`.

A block element such as a `div` defaults to `width: auto`, and takes the full available horizontal space. This is similar to how `width: 100%` works, except that `padding` and `border` are counted *inside* `width: auto`.

If `#exp_wrap` does not need to be absolutely positioned, use this: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/USvTC/2/

I removed `width: 100%` on `.bar_wrap`/`#exp_wrap` again, and replaced `position:absolute; top:5px; left:5px;` with `margin: 5px;`. I also added `overflow: hidden` to `.container` to avoid collapsing margins.

Comment: links are no longer available! I hate jsfiddle.

Comment: @AmirA.Shabani: [This jsFiddle bug](https://github.com/jsfiddle/jsfiddle-issues/issues/1388#issuecomment-436385224) is probably the reason why. I have not deleted anything so I can only assume that the jsFiddle user "weka" (the question OP, creator of the original demo) deleted his base demo, so my updates were also removed due to that bug. Fortunately my answer includes enough text description that it can hopefully still be useful, removing `width: 100%` if it's there is the main point.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the width of the child element to 512-(2*5) pixels in width (502), not 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the issue is the **box-sizing** of the child div. You can set it to **border-box** and then the child div shouldn't be longer than the parent div:

```
.child-div {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) about the box-sizing property.